# Azure Mobile Services Auth - We can't connect to the service

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, windows-10

I'm getting "We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this later." every now and then on my Windows 10 application when executing

```
user = await MyCloud.AzureClient.LoginAsync(provider, true);
```

Does anyone know the root cause of this error?
The app is connected to internet, checking internet connectivity of the app with

```
ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = 
                               NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with calling

```
LoginAsync(this IMobileServiceClient client, string provider, bool useSingleSignOn)
```

Single Sign On does not work well. Everything is working fine by just calling

```
LoginAsync(this IMobileServiceClient client, string provider)
```